# PHP Laravel: DB::insert returns a 500 error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm doing code in Laravel that inserts to a table in the database, but I am getting a 500 error:

```
    public function insert_prospect_to_database(){
        DB::insert('insert into recruiters (name) values (?)', array('james'));
    }
```

I can't figure out if the query is wrong or not, and the docs haven't much been of a help as well.

Comment: Please check the error.log on your DB server for the entry matching your attempted query and post it here.

Comment: 500 is internal server error - what does your HTTP logs say?

Comment: Try rewriting the query like: `DB::table('recruiters')->insert(
    array('name' => 'james'));`

Comment: can't find it :( in the console log it says 500 error XHR finished loading.

Comment: Without the error message I'm afraid there is nothing we can do to help you except poke in the dark and hope for sheer luck.

Comment: @Growlithe Is this still an issue? If yes please post the error message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Error Occurs while inserting data into the database.

Go to Storage/logs/laravel.log

See the error.

I changed the column default value to Null and it worked for me.